# Where to place ASP.NET Core website files in a Linux environment

Tags: linux, nginx, asp.net-core, debian

I'm deploying an ASP.NET Core 2.1 website to a Debian (Stretch) instance running nginx. Not being too familiar with Linux, I'm not sure where the standard/best place to deploy the website files to.

*(e.g. on IIS, the inetpub and directories under that were common to deploy to, though you could deploy it anywhere you want to if the proper folder permissions were given to the app pool processes)*

This [documented ASP.NET Core nginx deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) by MSFT doesn't mention where to put them.

Scott Hanselman's [post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx) kind of mentions the `/var` directory.

Where is the standard place to deploy a [ASP.NET Core] website in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs on hosting in linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x&WT.mc_id=aspnetcore-stackoverflow-shboyer#publish-and-copy-over-the-app) : It's common to locate web apps under the var directory for example, **var/aspnetcore/hellomvc**.

Comment: According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), the `/var` directory is used only for files which are expected to change during normal operation, such as logs or databases or system-wide data storage systems.  Application files that aren't supposed to change (i.e., read-only) but are available system-wide are stored in subfolders within the `/usr` directory tree.  If an app needs to be deployed in a dedicated folder then the `/opt` directory is more appropriate.